# Add result of same function to multiple variables without temporary variable

Tags: javascript, refactoring

This is what I have:

```
let num1 = 0;
let num2 = 5;

num1 += longFunction();
num2 += longFunction();
```

I know I can do this:

```
let num1 = 0;
let num2 = 5;

let _ = longFunction();
num1 += _;
num2 += _;
```

But this adds a temporary variable, which to me seems like it should be a code smell. I'm never going to use _ past those two lines.

Is there a way to do this without using a temporary variable, and while only calling the function once?

Comment: Since when is using a variable "code smell"?

Comment: what is wrong with a single variable? all other possibillities of caching requires more than a primitive value

Comment: It is not a code smell, but it sort of seems like it should be. If I'm working on a function with four or five temporary variables it kind of seems cluttered to me. It seems popular opinion is that having temporary variables is the clean way to do it so that is what I will continue to use temporary variables.

Comment: _"If I'm working on a function with four or five temporary variables"_ Your functions are too big. Break them down. Make them do one thing, but do it well. And as a bonus, they'll be way easier to test (if you do unit testing)

Comment: @blex, this is good advice, thank you. I'm working from someone else's code so I was trying to re-use as much as I can. But you're right, I'm going to simplify what I'm working on into smaller less complicated functions. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid a variable, here's one solution:

```js
let num1 = 0;
let num2 = 5;

[ , num1, num2] = [longFunction(), num1, num2].map(
  (n, i, arr) => n + arr[0]
)

console.log(num1, num2);


function longFunction() { return 5 }
```

*This* is code smell.

---

Here's an even "better" one.

```js
let num1 = 0;
let num2 = 5;

num2 = (num2 - num1) + (num1 += longFunction())

console.log(num1, num2);


function longFunction() { return 5 }
```

When assigning to `num2`, it preemptively subtracts `num1` from `num2`, but then adds to that the sum (assignment) of `longFunction` to `num1`, which is equivalent to simply adding `longFunction()` to `num2`.

Was fun to write, but of course, don't do this.

Comment: Clever, but yes, _"This is code smell."_. Never sacrifice readability over something as simple as creating a temporary variable

Comment: Didn't think I'd get a laugh when posting this, thanks!

Comment: @blex: Yeah, this was some sarcastic coding. I added another.

Comment: @BigBadBenny: Glad you enjoyed it! :)